# SPen - force commit action with commitHistory()

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-galaxy, stylus-pen

I am trying to draw a line between two points without releasing the pen from the screen and remove the rest of the line which is not between these two points.

[image]

Problem is if I don’t make an action up with the stylus, the line is not committed then all the line disappear (The line between the two point PLUS the rest of the line).

To make the rest of the line disappear I'm using the `undo()` method and I would like to use the `commitHistory()` method to keep the line between the two points. 
But this method needs a `SpenPageDoc.HistoryUpdateInfo` parameter and I don't know how to get this...

I am using the latest Samsung SPen SDK :
http://developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/sms/pen-light/index.html?com/samsung/android/sdk/pen/document/SpenPageDoc.HistoryListener.html

Thanks